# Запись информации из json ответа в базу данных

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

Я пишу приложение которое отправляет запросы api, и выводит их на консоль. Нужно реализовать возможность сохранения этого ответа в базу данных ms sql с помощью entity framework.
Вот класс в который я десериализую ответ api, как мне потом сохранить это в бд?

```
public class CountryInfo 
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "numericCode")]
    public string numericCode { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "capital")]
    public string Capital { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "area")]
    public double Area { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name ="population")]
    public decimal Population { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name ="region")]
    public  string Region { get; set; }       
}
```

Делаю запись как посоветовали в комментариях,

```
using (var context = new LocalDbContext())
{
    CountryInfo country = new CountryInfo();

    context.Countries.Add(new Country()
    {
        Name = country.Name,
        CountryCode = country.NumericCode,
        CountryArea = country.Area,
        Population = country.Population
    });

    context.Regions.Add(new Region()
    {
        RegionName = country.Region
    });

    context.Cities.Add(new City()
    {
        CityName = country.Capital
    });

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Но я не понимаю, каким образом, мне нужно передать полученную десериализованную информацию этому экземпляру класса, что бы через него сохранять информацию в бд.

Таблица Country, в столбцы которой нужно записать информацию.

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public int CapitalId { get; set; }
    public double CountryArea { get; set; }
    public decimal Population { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Capital { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Region> Region { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Как и любую другую информацию?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: И кто так сохраняет? Почитайте для начала документацию про то, чего пытаетесь использовать, а потом поймете, что в `Context` у вас должен быть объект нужной таблицы, это коллекция с которой идет работа при помощи простых `.Add()` методов. Например `context.Table.Add(new Country(){ Name = "" });`. Сохранить потом не забудьте (`context.SaveChanges();`).

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, бросьте в меня ссылкой пожалуйста. 
Просто я не понимаю, ведь с той формой записи, что указали вы, у меня все равно не получается в фигурных скобках записать в значение столбцов таблицы информацию из полей класса.

Comment: Например [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php)

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас вы создаёте новый экземпляр класса: `CountryInfo country = new CountryInfo();` Естественно, его свойства после этого пустые. Вместо этого вы должны получать объект с помощью сериализатора, что-то вроде: `CountryInfo county = serializer.Deserialize...`. Зависит от того, какой сериализатор вы используете.

Comment: Десериализировал информацию с помощью JsonConvert. 
Сейчас попробовал написать по вашему совету и либо я дурак, либо я дурак, потому что json ответ за полями видимости, и как к этому притянуть не понимаю. Так еще он приходит в массиве и для вывода ответа на консоль его пришлось в лист десериализовывать и циклом выводить нужное.